# Why does Minecraft keep crashing when I join a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The crash gave me this log:

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 307]
[01:31:10] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: kitten245
[01:31:15] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[01:31:17] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[01:31:39] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[01:31:39] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[01:31:39] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[01:31:40] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[01:31:40] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[01:31:44] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[01:31:55] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to mc.hypixel.net, 25565
[01:32:02] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]                                      
[01:32:02] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]                          
[01:32:02] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] You have 5 unclaimed leveling rewards!
[01:32:02] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] §eClick here to view them!
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000001c2dc933, pid=3684, tid=6504
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x6c933]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Sonia\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid3684.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

The Minecraft version I was using was 1.10.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't have all the information as to the cause of the problem, the one thing that shows up here to investigate is the following:

> ```
> # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
> # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
> # Problematic frame:
> # C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x6c933]
> ```

I found [a bug report](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-32606) about this issue on the tracker. It's not a direct issue with Minecraft but a possible issue with the Java install or with the video drivers. In this case, this problem is more likely a video driver issue.

You'll need to update the drivers, but I do not know what you are running directly, but it seems to be an Intel driver. Using the following link, you can visit their website to download a update utility that should find and fix this issue. http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html